# I have two select the second one is taking data from JSON which is stored in variable how to give on click

Tags: jquery, json

```
  <div class=" row text-center">
    text1 : <select id='A' name='A'>
    <option value='Select first' selected='selected'>Select first</option>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
  </select>
</div>

    <div class=" row text-center">
       text2 :<select id='B' name='B'></select></div>
```

this are the above 2 divs for select 1 and select 2.Select 2 value depens on select 1 and select 2 data is stored in variable as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {


var bOptions = {
"1": ["1","2","3","4","5"],
"2": ["2","4","6","8"],


};

var A = document.getElementById('A');
var B = document.getElementById('B');


A.onchange = function() {
//clear out B
B.length = 0;
//get the selected value from A
var _val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
//loop through bOption at the selected value
for (var i in bOptions[_val]) {
  //create option tag
  var op = document.createElement('option');
  //set its value
  op.value = bOptions[_val][i];
  //set the display label
  op.text = bOptions[_val][i];
  //append it to B
  B.appendChild(op);
}
 };
//fire this to update B on load
  A.onchange();

})();
</script>
```

when i click the second drop down list it should go to some link. ie how to redirect it to some url say 5.html when clicked 5(from 2nd drop down)

Comment: the question is really unclear :/

Comment: I have 2 select (drop down list) 2nd drop down list depend on the value of first.And the 2nd drop down data is stored in variable i want on click on that data

Comment: Are the arrays `["1,2,3,4,5,6"]` as one string? or the 1,2,3,4,5,6 at different positions?

Comment: different positions.

Comment: it is "1": ["1","2","3","4","5","6"],

Comment: Yea so put it that way, it should work then!!

Comment: it is working i am asking how to redirect it to some url say 5.html when clicked 5(from 2nd drop down).

Comment: Why dont you save the path to redirect in a `data-` attribute! , or else, just add a change function for `B` as well!

Comment: tried with change function it didn't work can you give me a code snippet.(if possible) how to use data attribute in script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like the second dropdown to contain each of the values from the array stored in bOptions that corresponds with the selection from the first dropdown, simply remove the quotes around your comma separated list.

**UPDATE1:**

If you would like the selection of the second dropdown to redirect to another page, you can add it to a function called by `$("#B").change()`.

**UPDATE2:**

If you want to store pairs of labels and url values, one way would be to include them both in your array with a special character you can use to separate them later.  You would apply one to `op.text` and the other to `op.value`.

```js
(function() {
  var bOptions = {
    "1": ["1:val1", "2:val2", "3:val3", "4:foo", "5:bar", "6:val6"],
    "2": ["2:val2", "4:val4", "6:val6", "8:val8", "10:val10"],
  };

  var A = document.getElementById('A');
  var B = document.getElementById('B');

  A.onchange = function() {
    //clear out B
    B.length = 0;
    //get the selected value from A
    var _val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    //loop through bOption at the selected value
    for (var i in bOptions[_val]) {
      //create option tag
      var op = document.createElement('option');
      //set its value
      op.value = bOptions[_val][i].split(":")[1];
      //set the display label
      op.text = bOptions[_val][i].split(":")[0];
      //append it to B
      B.appendChild(op);
    }
  };
  //fire this to update B on load
  A.onchange();

  $("#B").change(function() {
    var url = $(this).val() + ".html";
    alert(url); //added for testing, remove in your code
    window.location.href = url;
  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" row text-center">
  text1 : <select id='A' name='A'>
    <option value='Select first' selected='selected'>Select first</option>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class=" row text-center">
  text2 :<select id='B' name='B'></select></div>
```

Comment: i am getting that worked now when i click on the text2: drop down element it should redirect to some website say 3.html or 4.html

Comment: @Imzzy Please see my update to address this as well.

Comment: but i want to redirect to individual pages for all the elements not only one element say when you click 3 it should go to 3.html and when clicked 4 it should go to 4.html

Comment: It will do this, it is getting the selected value from your second dropdown and concatenating the value with ".html"

Comment: no no i meant i want custom url for each not to pass the value like 4 is the value but i want to redirect it to say foo.html when clicked 4 and bar.html when clicked 5

Comment: You need to store that associated information somewhere.  I'll update code to give one possible solution.

Comment: @Imzzy please see my second update for an option to store and use text/value pairs

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged the question in jQuery,

```
$('#A').on('change',function(){
   let currentVal = $(this).val() + "";
   var values = bOptions[currentVal];
   if(values.length)  
   {
       for(var z = 0 ; z < values.length ; z++)
       {
           $('#B').append("<option value='"+values[z]+"'>"+values[z]+"</option>");
       }
   }
});
```

Since you added it later for the redirect thing!

```
$(document).on('change','#B' , function(){
   let currentVal = $(this).val() + "";
   var tmpFile = currentVal + '.html';
   window.location.href = tmpFile;
});
```

Comment: that will redirect all the values to same html content i want it to redirect to individual content click 3 it should go to 3.html and when clicked 4 it should go to 4.html

Comment: It wont go to the same page each time, it will depend on the second select box

Comment: no no i meant i want custom url for each not to pass the value like 4 is the value but i want to redirect it to say foo.html when clicked 4 and bar.html when clicked 5

Comment: @Imzzy You really need to mention that in the question, and then instead of keeping an array in bOptions , you can keep file paths and as I suggested earlier save it in the `data-` attribute of the option tags. Then onchange of  just get the `data-` attribute and redirect!

Comment: Sorry i dint mention it in the begginning about the question.don't want to use data attribute is there any other way via which we can redirect it to custom url

Comment: Then your `bOptions` can be an object instead of an array, with a mapping of each value to a URL.Hardcoding the URLs in a if-else would be a wrong approach.